# How to add test coverage for CustomHttpOverrides in flutter?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, sonarqube

[sonarQube result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjOvm.png)

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class CustomHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  ByteData data;
  CustomHttpOverrides(this.data);

  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    final SecurityContext clientContext = SecurityContext()..setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    return super.createHttpClient(clientContext);
  }
}
```

Does anybody know how to add unit tests for this CustomHttpOverrides class?

Comment: Have you tried to pass a non-ByteData and a non-SecurityContext to your tests? It would be nice having the unit test code you wrote for this class so We can help!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)